# What can you conclude about the holomorphic function f?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The problems is as follows:

Suppose $0<r<1, A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: r<|z|<1\}, f:\bar{A}\to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, and $f$ is holomorphic on $A$, and vanishes on the unit circle. What can you conclude about $f$?

Attempt at a solution:

Since $f$ is continuous on $\bar {A}$, then by the maximum principle $f$ attains its maximum on the boundary of $\bar{A}$. That is; $$|f(z)|\leq \max\{M(r), M(1)\}$$ where $M(x)=sup_{|z|=x}|f(z)|$.

Since $f(z)=0$ for all $|z|=1$, then  $|f(z)|\leq \max\{M(r), 0\}$.

So, clearly $f\equiv 0$ on $A$ if $f$ attains it's maximum on the unit circle. 
If, however, $f$ attains it's maximum on the inner circle, I'm not sure what else can be said about $f ?$

Comment: By Cauchy's Theorem:
$\int_{|z|=r} f(z)\, dz= \int_{|z|=1} f(z)\, dz = 0$.  Thus sum of residues inside the smaller circle is zero.

Comment: @SouravD That is correct! I guess the question is of an open ended nature. The way I interpreted it was more like classifying all such $f$, but that might not be what the problem intended.

Comment: Yes, A little bit of context would have been helpful as to what kind of characteristics of $f$ do we investigate. 
I also noticed that, from your deduction, $|f(z)| \leq \max\{M(r)\}$ is a more refined conclusion. If $f$ assumes any non-zero value on $|z|=r$, then that is its maximum or else it will anyway be zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$g(z) = f(z)f\Big(\frac{r}{z}\Big).$$

Then $g$ is holomorphic on $A$ and continuous on $\bar A$. Also, $g = 0$ on $\partial A$, so by the maximum modulus principle, $g = 0$ everywhere on $A$. The identity theorem forces one of the factors to vanish on $A$, so in any case $f=0$ on $A$.

Comment: This is great, thanks!